# Is SqlCommand the only way of adding,deleting and updating records?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am currently creating a Windows Forms application that has 4 buttons, an Update, Add, Delete and Cancel button. My information that I have within my records goes directly into my textboxes, and I have used a `SqlCommand cmd;`.

I have added this in my Add button click handler:

```
private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (true)
    {
        Utilities.ResetAllControls(this);
        connection.Open();

        cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into tblCar values('" + txtbxVehicleRegistrationNumber.Text + "','" + txtbxMake.Text + "','" + txtbxEngineSize.Text + "','" + txtbxDateRegistered + "','" + txtbxRentalPerDay + "','" + CbxAvailable.Checked + "')", connection);

        MessageBox.Show("Your information has been successfully added.");
        connection.Close();
    }
}
```

The `Utilities` listed is a class that I have created. Is this the right way that I am going about adding data? Also I want to know how (upon clicking the Add button) clears all existing data for me from the textboxes (but not deleting them) to add new ones. I'd appreciate if someone helps me with this predicament of mine.

The `Utilities` class is:

```
public class Utilities
{
    public static void ResetAllControls(Control form)
    {
        foreach (Control control in form.Controls)
        {
            if (control is TextBox)
            {
                TextBox textBox = (TextBox)control;
                textBox.Text = null;
            }

            if (control is ComboBox)
            {
                ComboBox comboBox = (ComboBox)control;

                if (comboBox.Items.Count > 0)
                     comboBox.SelectedIndex = 0;
            }

            if (control is CheckBox)
            {
                CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox)control;
                checkBox.Checked = false;
            }

            if (control is ListBox)
            {
                ListBox listBox = (ListBox)control;
                listBox.ClearSelected();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You have a SQL injection vulnerability.

Comment: No, you do nto have to use DBCommand objects.  A DataAdapter obviates the need for them (and connection objects).  Which to do depends on what you are up to

Comment: SQLCommand is typically used for MSSQL, not MySQL.

Comment: @SLaks  Could you explain where the threat of an SQL injection will occur,is it most likely in the user input or DBConnection?

Comment: @Plutonix How would i be able to use a tableadapter to insert data

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/data-tools/fill-datasets-by-using-tableadapters?view=vs-2015

Comment: Do not glue bits of string together for the SQL.  Use SQL Parameters.  Gobs of posts here and on MSDN  on the tools you are using.  (Note that a TableAdapter is not the same as a DataAdapter)

Comment: @Plutonix Thanks.I'm still new to the use of Adapters in WindowsFormApplication

Comment: Yea, thats why it would behoove you to rush over to MSDN and read up on them.  This is not a tutorial site.

Comment: Use prepared statements with placeholder values to avoid [problems like this](http://bobby-tables.com). They're often less work, lead to more readable code, and will save you hours of frustrating debugging because you forgot to escape something correctly.

Comment: Your risk for injection is related to not validating your inputs (the `.Text` properties), nor putting them into parameters in your queries.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your code seems fine to me, and I am unsure as to what your exact issue is; however, to clear your `TextBox` control's `.Text` property; assign it a value of `string.Empty`.

```
textBox1.Text = string.Empty;
```

As far as your insert command, that looks fine. A point has been made that your code is vulnerable to [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection), but unless you need to safeguard your information, then I wouldn't worry too much. If you are worried about SQL Injection and how to protect against it, there are many posts here, and many articles online on how to protect your applications from this type of attack. Things to look into are:

- Parameterization of dynamic data and queries.
- Don't overuse dynamically generated queries.
- Utilize `sp_executesql` when executing dynamic queries so that parameters can't be manipulated.

Comment: I appreciate anonymous downvotes are annoying, but they are allowed, and no-one is under any obligation to explain them. You may ask for an explanation in a comment if you wish, but it's probably a waste of time. We'd rather not have notes about voting in posts though, since it is not of interest to most readers (who do not sign in or vote).